# Very slow FTP download

Tags: java, download, ftp

I'm downloading a file from a FTP account using a self written function:

```
private boolean download(String path, Path target) throws IOException {
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(target.toString());
    boolean download = client.retrieveFile(path, fos);
    fos.close();
    return download;
}
```

`client` is a `org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient` object. Unfortunately the download speed of this function is very very slow. Why is this the case and how can I increase it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you can try increasing the buffer size of your client object, like this:`client.setBufferSize(1024000);`

This will decrease the buffer copies on your end, and speed up the download, as commented in [SpeedUp FTPClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11572588/speed-up-apache-commons-ftpclient-transfer)

Answer (score 1):

Before you do the retrieve, or where you setup your client, try increasing the buffer size.

```
client.setBufferSize(1024*1024);
```